# when I send data with ajax php wont get anything

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

post and get works fine but json returns wrong value , or something is wrong with my php code.

```
  $(function () {
   $('#username').on('keypress',function () {
      var input = $('#username').val();
       if(input.length>=4){
           $.ajax({
               url:'registration_php.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data:{username:input},
               success:function () {
                   $.getJSON('registration_php.php',function (text) {
                       alert(text.user);
                   });
               }
           });
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: here is image https://s21.postimg.org/pe4785ak7/Capture.png

Comment: Why are you call ajax two times for the same server link ? Because $.getJSON and $.ajax are equivalents.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is a shortcut for `$.ajax`, you're making an ajax call twice

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(result) {
                   var items = JSON.parse(result);
                   alert(items['user']);
                 }
```

pass the result directly to your reponse as an argument like this

Answer (score 0):

you should specify a dataType: "json" in your ajax call

```
      var postData = JSON.stringify({
        username: 'value'
      });
       var request = $.ajax({
            url: "registration_php.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: postData,
        });

        request.success(function( results ) {
            console.log(results)
        });
```